# Comparing By Value in Java8 returning weird results

Tags: java, dictionary, java-8

I am trying to sort a map based on the value.

But I am seeing some weird behavior for the following program

```
public class CompareByValueMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String,Integer> itemIDToTimeMap = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

        itemIDToTimeMap.put("Baggage", 3);
        itemIDToTimeMap.put("Handbag", 16);
        itemIDToTimeMap.put("Closed Footwear", 4);
        itemIDToTimeMap.put("Shirt", 25);

        Set<String> itemIDs = itemIDToTimeMap.entrySet().stream()
                .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()))
                .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());

        System.out.println(itemIDs);
    }
}
```

The output is turned out to be correct

[Shirt, Handbag, Closed Footwear, **Baggage**]

But in the input when I change from **Baggage** to **Bag**
It is giving the following output

[Shirt, **Bag**, Handbag, Closed Footwear]

Ideally sorting should be done based on the Value in the Map irrespective of the key values. But Not sure why it is changing if the key is changed here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem is here:

```
.collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

because `Collectors.toSet()` returns `HashSet` which is not ordered (since in most cases we don't really need an order in sets, but speed of its `contains` method which `HashSet` provides).

Use `LinkedHashSet` if you want to preserve insertion order

```
.collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new));
```

---

Or depending on how you want to use this result maybe use List instead?

Answer (score 8):

**You are collecting the results into a `Set`. Not all `Set`s guarantee order.**

So the sort works fine, but afterwards it is stored in a container that does not bother about the order of the Strings.

Use a container like `List<>` to store your data, after the sort has finished. This will guarantee the order of your items.

```
public class CompareByValueMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String,Integer> itemIDToTimeMap = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

        itemIDToTimeMap.put("Bag", 3); // already changed to "Bag" to demonstrate the working code
        itemIDToTimeMap.put("Handbag", 16);
        itemIDToTimeMap.put("Closed Footwear", 4);
        itemIDToTimeMap.put("Shirt", 25);

        List<String> itemIDs = // use List<> instead of Set<>
                itemIDToTimeMap.entrySet().stream()
                .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()))
                .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                .collect(Collectors.toList()); // use .toList() instead of .toSet()

        System.out.println(itemIDs);
    }
}
```

A simple example to demonstrate the difference:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("List:");
    Stream
        .of("b", "a")
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
        .stream()
        .forEach(System.out::println);

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Set:");
    Stream
        .of("b", "a")
        .collect(Collectors.toSet())
        .stream()
        .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

which outputs:

```
List:
b
a

Set:
a
b
```

Comment: @slartidan For me the problem is the word `shuffle`. To me, that implies that the order is random, whereas your last block of code shows that it is not. A better way of putting it is that `Collectors.toSet` does not keep the original order.

Answer (score 4):

The default `toSet()` collector returns an `HashSet` which does not retain the insertion order.

See the implementation in 8u60 (note that this is an internal detail):

```
public static <T> Collector<T, ?, Set<T>> toSet() {
    return new CollectorImpl<>((Supplier<Set<T>>) HashSet::new, Set::add,
                               (left, right) -> { left.addAll(right); return left; },
                               CH_UNORDERED_ID);
}
```

You can use `.collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new));` to provide a specific implementation instead (which will retain the insertion order).